# Should it be "in, at or with an exchange rate of 2:1"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Should it be "in, at or with an exchange rate of 2:1"? I am not sure what the right preposition is for the expression "exchange rate of". All of them sounds fine to me, but I think at least one of them might be wrong.

For example:

> You can exchange a Canadian Dollar for a U.S. dollar at an exchange
>   rate of 10 to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of prepositions follows obscure, perhaps non-existent, rules.

> at an exchange rate of

and

> for an exchange rate

are idiomatic in the financial industry. I have never heard "with" or "in" used in that phrase